# how to select two table mysql use php

Tags: php, mysql

Ex: i have two table:
table 1:

```
 ________________________________
| ID | name          | born      |
|--------------------------------|
| 1  | David         | 1987      |
| 2  | Michale       | 1998      |
| 3  | Mary          | 1995      |
 --------------------------------
```

table 2

```
 _________________________________
| userID | Key        | value     |
 ---------------------------------
| 2      | D of Birth | 20-07     |
| 2      | sex        | M         |
| 3      | D of Birth | 12-09     |
| 3      | sex        | FM        |
| 1      | D of Birth | 20-01     |
| 1      | sex        | M         |
 ---------------------------------
```

how can i select and add to array as:

```
Array 
  [0]
     [ID] = 1
     [name] = David
     [born] = 1987
     [D o Birth] = 20-01
     [sex] = M
  [1]
     [ID] = 2
     [name] = Michale
     [born] = 1998
     [D o Birth] = 20-07
     [sex] = M
  ...
```

I don't know why they not use one table for simple? two table are faster query?
Many Thanks!

Comment: `Key` is a terrible name for a column (it is a reserved term, will need to be backticked), and poor DB design. Each `key` should be a column in the table, then you could use a standard `join` for this.

Comment: this old database, so i must be use this! thank for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [crosstab](http://libguides.library.kent.edu/SPSS/Crosstabs). With a crosstab, rows can become columns and visa versa.

Unfortunately MySQL doesn't have a crosstab support. So you need to create a custom query:

```
SELECT user.*, dofbirth.value AS `D of Birth`, sex.value AS sex
  FROM user
    LEFT JOIN userprop AS dofbirth
      ON dofbirth.key = 'D of Birth' AND user.id = dofbirth.userID
    LEFT JOIN userprop AS sex
      ON sex.key = 'sex' AND user.id = `sex`.userID
```

You need to know the columns in advance, so you need to know the keys of the `userprop` table in advance.

---

You could get all the keys with the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT key FROM userprop
```

Than you need to loop though the keys in PHP and build up the crosstab query.

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT key FROM userprop");

$cols = ["user.*"];
$from = "user";

while (list($key) = $result->fetch_row()) {
  $table = strtolower(preg_replace('/\W/', $key));

  $cols[] = "{$table}.value AS `" . str_replace('`', '', $key) . "`";
  $from .= " LEFT JOIN userprop AS `{$table}` ON `{$table}`.key = \"" . $db->real_escape_string($key) . "\" AND `{$table}`.userID = user.id"; 
}

$query = "SELECT " . join(', ', $cols) . " FROM " . $from;
...
```